# How to create Athena table through parquet from pandas?

Tags: pandas, hive, parquet, amazon-athena

I start with a pandas Dataframe and saved to parquet format as such:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    {'abc': 1.231, 'xyz':2, 'jkl': False, 'idx': 'first row', 'date': '2023-12-01'},
    {'abc': 9.123, 'xyz':5, 'jkl': True, 'idx': '2nd row', 'date': '2023-12-04'}
])

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')

df.to_parquet('x.parq')
```

And when I check the schema with `parquet-cli`, it shows:

```
parq x.parq --schema
```

[out]:

```
# Schema 
 <pyarrow._parquet.ParquetSchema object at 0x7f9f4b365400>
required group field_id=-1 schema {
  optional double field_id=-1 abc;
  optional int64 field_id=-1 xyz;
  optional boolean field_id=-1 jkl;
  optional binary field_id=-1 idx (String);
  optional int64 field_id=-1 date (Timestamp(isAdjustedToUTC=false, timeUnit=microseconds, is_from_converted_type=false, force_set_converted_type=false));
}
```

The parquet file is then saved to `s3://mybucket/` and when I have tried to create a table in AWS Athena, e.g.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`table1` (
  abc float, 
  xyz int, 
  jkl boolean,
  idx string,
  date date
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat' OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.paruqet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
LOCATION 's3://mybucket/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('classification' = 'parquet');
```

The query run successfully and showed no error. Then when I tried to query the table,

```
SELECT * from mydb.table1;
```

It's showing the error:

```
HIVE_CURSOR_ERROR: Failed to read Parquet file s3://mybucket/x.parq
```

**Was the CTAS query written wrongly? Wrong type definition?**

**How do I correctly convert the parquet file to the Athena table where it can be queried?**

**Is there's an easier way to write the pandas dataframe out to parquet or anyother format so that it can be easily read as athena table?**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the AWS SDK for Pandas, instead.

```
wr.s3.to_parquet(
    df=df,
    path="s3://bucket/dataset/",
    dataset=True,
    database="my_db",
    table="my_table"
)
```

and then

```
wr.athena.read_sql_query(
    "SELECT * FROM my_table", 
    database="my_db", 
    ctas_approach=False
)
```

reference: https://aws-sdk-pandas.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/006%20-%20Amazon%20Athena.html

Comment: While this work with a small dataframe, I'll have to load all the parquet files from the S3 bucket before awswrangler push it to parquet. Is there some way to go directly from the parquet files in S3 path to the athena tables?